# Помогите, пожалуйста. Не могу понять в чём ошибка. При запуске выдаёт ошибку: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *


class Play_Buttons(Button):  # класс на основе которого, создаются кнопки с определёнными параметрами

    def __init__(self, font=20, background=5,
                 padx=20, pady=8, command=None, is_wrong_button=False):  # иницилизация кнопок
        super(Button, self).__init__(font, background, padx, pady, command)
        self.is_wrong_button = is_wrong_button

    def game_button(self, letter):  # делает кнопки с определёнными параметрами
        return Button(text=letter,
                      font=20,
                      bd=5,
                      padx=20,
                      pady=8,
                      command=lambda: self.addpop(letter)
                      )

    @staticmethod
    def addpop(letter):  # функция кнопки (просто есть, особой роли не играет)
        print(letter)


root = Tk()

btn = Play_Buttons()
btn.game_button('А')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: При вызове `__init__` родительского класса передавайте все через именованные параметры: `super().__init__(font=font, background=background, padx=padx, pady=pady, command=command)`.

Comment: По коду: bd=5 - это не background, а сокращение от border, имеется в виду толщина границы, background - цвет фона. При передаче background=5 в родительский `__init__` будет ругаться, что нет такого цвета 5. Ну и не понятно, зачем тут вообще наследование от Button, если в итоге вы похоже будете через метод game_button создавать обычные кнопки.